# Products not shown in shopping cart when add to cart is clicked

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart

I have made one custom module. Where i want to show some custom related products on product page.

> **I select the product with checkbox to add to cart and When i click add to cart, products are added in cart but not shown in shopping cart See**

[image]

> **When i refresh the page the products appear in the cart See**

[image]

This is happening only with my custom module.
Default magento functionality works well.

> **My Controller action code**

```
    <?php

       namespace MagePal\LinkProduct\Controller\Index;

     use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
     use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
     use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
     use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
    use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

     use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

         class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_customerSessionFactory;
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $cacheTypeList;
    protected $cacheFrontendPool;
    protected $_registry;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $formKey;protected $cart;
    protected $productFactory;


    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSessionFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool, \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
      
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
     $productCollectionFactory,FormKey $formKey,
       Cart $cart,
         // Product $product
       ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
       // $this->product = $product;
         $this->productFactory = $productFactory;



        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        // $categoryIdAjax = $this->getRequest()->getParam('catId');
        // $optionValueAjax = $this->getRequest()->getParam('optionValue');
        $dataId = json_decode(stripslashes($this->getRequest()->getParam('data')));
        
        foreach ($dataId as $productId) {
         $params = array(
                            'form_key' =>$this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                            'qty'   =>3, //quantity of product                
                            
                            );
        // $product = $this->productFactory->load($dataId);
        print_r($params);
         $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);

        }
         $this->cart->save();
        
        // $productId=1;
         $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $result->setData($productId);
          
    }

}
```

Js script

```
<script>
require(
    [
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $
        ) {
        

        $("#submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchIDs = $(".test input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
}).get(); // <----
            var quantity =  $("#quantity").val();
                        product_data = {
                ids: searchIDs,
                qty: quantity
                       }
            var addCartUrl = "<?php echo $baseUrl . 'linkproduct/index/index' ?>";
            
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST', showLoader: true,
                url: addCartUrl,
                data: {data : JSON.stringify(product_data)}, 
                success: function (data) {
                  
                    console.log(data);
                    

                },
                error: function (request, error)
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
            return false;

        });

    }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add this script to your **phtml** file

```
<script>
require(
    [
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function($,customerData) {
        

        $("#submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchIDs = $(".test input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
}).get(); // <----
            var quantity =  $("#quantity").val();
                        product_data = {
                ids: searchIDs,
                qty: quantity
                       }
            var addCartUrl = "<?php echo $baseUrl . 'linkproduct/index/index' ?>";
            
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST', showLoader: true,
                url: addCartUrl,
                data: {data : JSON.stringify(product_data)}, 
                success: function (data) {
                    var sections = ['cart'];
                    customerData.invalidate(sections);
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (request, error)
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            });
            return false;

        });

    }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work

Comment: have you add this code on your phtml file ? not in js file ok

Comment: yes added in phtml file

Comment: My phtml file contains one more script, so added this script after that. check my post for script

Comment: please share your code

Comment: added in post...........

Comment: add at last of your code.please check update answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109871/discussion-between-nafisa-and-msquare).

Comment: This worked for me. thank u