# How to reload shopping cart items?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ajax, ajaxaddtocart

I added a module to automatically update shopping cart by Ajax which works fine.
Basically, when I change the item qty in the shopping cart, it will automatically update the shopping cart subtotal and cart summary.

But when I update the item qty on minicart, it only reload/update the cart summary but not the shopping cart items qty and subtotal. How can I fix this?

Ajax Update

Created a new module:

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Learning_AutoUpdateCart',
     __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_AutoUpdateCart" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart.auto.update.qty"  template="Learning_AutoUpdateCart::js.phtml" after="-"/>


    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/templates/js.phtml

```
<script>
require ([
        'jquery'
    ],
    function ($) {
        $(window).on("load", function () {
            require([
                'Learning_AutoUpdateCart/js/cartQtyUpdate'
            ]);
        });
    });
```

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/web/js/cartQtyUpdate.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                /* Minicart reloading */
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                /* Totals summary reloading */
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           ajaxQty: 'Learning_AutoUpdateCart/js/cartQtyUpdate'
        }
   }
};
```

Comment: We need to know the code summary for ajax upate of this.

Comment: @RiteshSantra sorry, I have updated the post with the code.

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code

**app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/web/js/cartQtyUpdate.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");


                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                /* Minicart reloading */
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.invalidate(sections);
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                /* Totals summary reloading */
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: Thanks, that works @Msquare. does it always have to reload the whole page when I update the qty of item in the minicart?

Comment: the checkout cart page https://local.com/checkout/cart/. It reloads the whole page after changing the qty in the minicart.

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/235041/82670

Comment: does "customerData.invalidate" checks for the stock status? and if it does, is there any way to display a message like "the qty you asked is not available" when a user change/increases the items's quantity to something higher than the stock available.

Comment: yes customerData.invalidate(sections); that remove old data and add new data customerData.reload(sections, true); using this

Comment: is there any way for the function to return success or error?

Comment: yes you can get data into var sections = ['cart']; by checking this you can return success or error.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please give me an example of how it returns. Thank you.

Comment: please rise your question i will post answer.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321878/magento-2-how-to-display-messages-on-ajax-success-change here is my question post.

Comment: Hi, would you like me to create a new question? (something different than the one above) @Msquare

Comment: what will happen if I add the exceeded Qty for the product?

Comment: default magento addtocart controller return error if Qty  exceeded for the product.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code as below in file

app/code/Learning/AutoUpdateCart/view/frontend/web/js/cartQtyUpdate.js

**From:**

```
var sections = ['cart'];

$("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

/* Minicart reloading */
customerData.reload(sections, true);
```

**To:**

```
$("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

/* Minicart reloading */
var sections = ['cart'];
customerData.invalidate(sections);
customerData.reload(sections, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works @RiteshSantra. does it always have to reload the whole page when I update the qty of item in the minicart?

Comment: It is not reload the whole page. It is only reload the minicart section.

Comment: is there a way to update minicart without having to click "update button"? @RiteshSantra

Comment: You can remove the update button and reload the minicart after keyup for every change in qty field or can use dropdown in qty field.